# sum of first and last digit of integer in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
  int n,first,last,digits;
  cin>>n;
  last=n%10;
  digits=log10(n);
  first=n/pow(10,digits);
  cout<<first+last;`
}
```

The above code shows 2 as output for the input 0101 but it should show 1.since 0+1=1.can anyone suggest code in c++?

Comment: Hint: 0101 = 101. Besides, I don't think this code can provide the good result

Comment: Please explain logic of  ```first = log10(n) + 1``` to get the first digit.

Comment: "0101" is read as an integer in octal, so it is 65. And `log10(101) + 1` is 3, so you definitely need a better algorithm.

Comment: If you want to care about leading zeros, you need to read strings.

Comment: if n is 100 then log10(n) = 2. log10(n) will give the exponent of 10.

Comment: @HarishSubramani Is log10(100) + 1 (which is 3) the first digit of 100?

Answer (score 0):

Your input is 0101 into n. n is an `int`. So the preceding useless 0 in 0101 is shaved off and you get the correct answer for 101 (1 + 1 = 2). You'll need to use a string if you want to get 1 for 0101.

Answer (score 0):

It's a math, you can expression to get the first (most significant digit) of an integer number:

```
first = n / static_cast<int>(pow(10, static_cast<int>(log10(n))));
```